# using FBA can create a new account but people picker doesn't recognize it

Tags: forms-authentication

I am using FBA on a wss 3.0 site, I can create new users in the DB by using the ASP.NET management site.  The users can then log in, but receive an error: access denied message.

So, I know that the accounts are being authenticated properly (since when i type the username or password incorrectly I get a different message, "the server could not sign you in")

I have working fba accounts on the site since I set this up over a year ago.  I can log in fine using those, and the people picker recognizes those accounts with membership provider i.e.:  FBAMember:testaccount - the people picker will recognize this and allow me to add it to more groups.

But the picker does not recognize any of the accounts I just created using the management tool, using the same connection string i'm using in the web.config of the sp site.

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Thanks

EDIT:
So, FBAMember:membername is listed as the account name for the accounts already in sharepoint, but I can't even add those accounts to a new group, I get a SP error "the user or group is unknown". .. so, these users can log in, but for some reason that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add the wildcard setting to the PeoplePicker element in web.config?

Comment: could you elobarte a bit on this setting?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975136(office.12).aspx#MOSS2007FBAPart1_BasicSetup

Comment: Is it the peoplepicker settings need to be added for all the web.configs? or only the custom web application's web.config.